# Simple circle geometry/ similarity question

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

How would you prove that $a=b$ ?
Would it be possible to solve this using similarity or trigonometry?

[image: $X$ and $Y$ are the centers of the circles]

Thank you in advance for any help. Any theorems or links would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you talking of **angles** $\;a,b\;$ or what?

Comment: @DonAntonio yes, I am talking about the angles a and b

Comment: If the cord in the big circle were a tangent to the small circle on the upper intersection point between both circles, I think I've a solution. Are you sure this is not given in the problem, @Berry ?

Comment: @DonAntonio no, that is what the diagram should be like

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

$\angle ABD+\angle AGD=\pi$ $\Longrightarrow$ $\angle ABC=\angle AGD$ $\Longrightarrow$ $\angle AEC=\angle AFD~$ and $~\dfrac{AE}{EC}=\dfrac{AF}{FD}$
$\therefore$ $\triangle AEC\sim\triangle AFD$

Comment: I have two comments about your solution. (1) By "exterior angle of cyclic quadrilateral", $\angle ABC=\angle AGD$ and therefore no implication like "$\angle ABD+\angle AGD=\pi$" is needed.

Comment: (2) To certain degree, your drawing seems to be requiring  E, A and G to be on the same straight line. Such requirement is clearly not needed.

Comment: "by exterior angle of cyclic quadrilateral" is not proof.

Comment: $G$ is arbitrary point on circumcircle of $\triangle ABD$.

Comment: $G$ is for $\angle AFD$.

Comment: What did you use to make that wonderful diagram?

Comment: I use GeoGebra for diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

I take the picture to illustrate this scenario: Circles $\bigcirc X$ and $\bigcirc Y$, of respective radii $r$ and $s$, intersect at $P$ and $Q$. A line through $Q$ meets the circles at $A$ and $B$.

[image]

Now, $\triangle XAP$ and $\triangle YBP$ are isosceles, with
$$\frac{|XA|}{|YB|} = \frac{|XP|}{|YP|} = \frac{r}{s}$$ 
If we can show also that 
$$\frac{|AP|}{|BP|} = \frac{r}{s} \qquad (\star)$$
then the triangles will be *similar*, and their base angles, *congruent*.

Recall that the Law of Sines relates angles and sides of a triangle, *as well as the diameter of the circumcircle*. So, for instance, in $\triangle APQ$,
$$\frac{|PQ|}{\sin\angle PAQ} = \frac{|AP|}{\sin\angle AQP} = \frac{|AQ|}{\sin\angle APQ} = 2 r$$
Of importance to us is that
$$|PQ| = 2r \sin\angle PAQ$$
Likewise, in $\triangle BPQ$,
$$|PQ| = 2s \sin\angle PBQ$$
We now apply the Law of Sines to $\triangle APB$ to get
$$\frac{|AP|}{|BP|} = \frac{\sin\angle PBQ}{\sin\angle PAQ} = \frac{|PQ|/(2s)}{|PQ|/(2r)} = \frac{r}{s}$$
proving $(\star)$.

Answer (score 1):

- LET THE CENTRE OF THE TWO TRIANGLE ARE  O & P
- now a  =$\frac{180-t}{2}$;  now t=2l
- SO a=$\frac{180-2l}{2}$
- NOW again b =$\frac{180-x}{2}$; x=2f and f=180 $-$n
- SO b =$\frac{2n-180}{2}$
- we see (n+l)=180; FROM THIS WE GET $\frac{180-2l}{2}$ =$\frac{2n-180}{2}$
- so a=b[image]